# How do I change function after clicking buttons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I have three functions A(),B(),C()

```
<input type="button" value="text"  id="Button" onclick="A()"></input>
```

What should I write in function A() to make it into

```
<input type="button" value="text"  id="Button" onclick="B()"></input>
```

after I click the button.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to let the same button run another function after the first one

Comment: No I understand that, but what's the overall goal of your code? This seems like a sloppy way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Change attribute after click:

```
<input type="button" value="text"  id="Button" onclick="B();this.setAttribute('onclick','A()')"></input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ye87k/

Comment: Awesome adding the jsfiddle